Could neuroplasticity correlate with kinds of intelligence?
If neuroplasticity is something like the brain’s ability to form new synapses, it sounds like the brain can change itself, as a cognitive system, leading to new thinking patterns.
I sometimes wonder if the ability to learn new things has anything to do with this - when we learn something new, I think we develop a layered mental model of something. By layered, I mean we sometimes need a hierarchy of concepts, and higher-order relationships, to understand something.
I am wondering if for some reason, some people’s brains have higher neuroplasticity than others’, so their brain rewires itself much faster, making them much more able to build those mental models of new things.
I’m also curious if this has anything to do with open-mindedness - like, it’s much harder for intellectually rigid people to rewrite their worldview; open minded people have to be intellectually active, because when they encounter a new idea, they have to dynamically update their entire mental system to incorporate that new idea into their other thoughts, beliefs, mental models, etc.
